# SharePoint Provider hostes App Update delete all my list Data

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have create a providerhosted app with several lists in it. 
A List contains a Contenttype that holds the listcolumns.

Now I added a new Column to the contenttype. 
I also add a update Entry in my feature like the following

```
<UpgradeActions>
<VersionRange BeginVersion="1.0.0.0" EndVersion="1.1.0.0">
  <AddContentTypeField ContentTypeId="0x0100ACBE1A40F4DF4E0E9EFAD0092F92C10400E15F2E9BCA8F4E6590C82C6A4445197A"
                       FieldId="{8dd75734-5222-4eb0-bcb5-c9eb721fe969}" PushDown="true"/>
</VersionRange>
```

I increase the versionnumber in the app manifest.

After I Hit F5 from my Visual Studio, I go to the list and the "Upgradeproceess" deletes all entries in it.

How can i prevent this? Because a column insert couses no data lost I think. Or is that a normal procedure in a developer site?

What happens when I deploy this to a production enviorment? Does it delete the data too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that an F5 deploy from VS does a full uninstall/install for SharePoint Apps instead of invoking an Upgrade. Can you check the Output window when you hit F5? It should show the App being uninstalled?

I would Publish your App and Update it in the App Catalog manually. Then you can know for sure if your UpgradeActions are acting weird.

This article is a good read for Updating components in the App Web: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn265911(v=office.15).aspx

Most declarative actions are similar to deploying/upgrading Sandbox solutions with some slight differences.

Comment: Thx for your reply, and yes it does a full redeploy. But only when I change anything in the sharepoint app. Is it not possible to prevent the reinstall?

Comment: thx for your reply, and yes it does a reinstall. Is it not possibly to disable the reinstallation.otherwise I take your solution.

Comment: If you mean change the action in Visual Studio? Then I'm not sure on this. If you look at how Sandboxed solutions deployed through VS then they also could not be upgraded through the F5 deploy method either. 
You should however be able to update the remote components e.g. Provider Hosted App 'site' without needing to touch the SharePoint App piece.